# Emails sent from Thunderbird not Showing up in Office365 OWA

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, office365

We are facing a strange issue. I recently got O365 subscriptions and created a new email account there.

The user then installed Thunderbird and started sending/receiving emails. They would also go to O365 OWA (https://outlook.office365.com) and login to their account to send/receive emails.

The problem is - When the user sends emails from Thunderbird it doesn't show up in Sent Folder on OWA and when sent through OWA, it doesn't show up in ThunderBird Sent Folder.

Is there anything we need to do to make this work? - i.e. See all the Sent emails in Sent Folder on OWA or Thunderbird irrespective of where there are sent from.

PS: This is true when we use other mail clients like Microsoft Live Mail. Apparently it would only work if we use Outlook client and select Exchange Server and Auto-Discover in settings.

Comment: I assume you are using IMAP on TB? Have you configured the account in TB to use the remote sent items folder for sent emails?

Comment: That's right, we are using IMAP. Sorry, I havent used TB much.. how do I configure TB to use the remote sent items folder?

Comment: I think you were referring to the setting which says -- Place a Copy in --> Sent Folder on:.? That's set to the email server or my mailbox on the email server

Comment: Correct, it should be the sent items folder on the server.

Answer (score 4):

In Thunderbird, there is a local Sent Items and there is the IMAP Sent Items which is stored on the server:

- To specify where sent messages saved, go to Tools > Account Settings...
- Copies > Folders
- Confirm "Place a copy" is checked on
- Choose Other
- Select the correct folder ("IMAP Sent Items")

You may also need to check on more IMAP folders to show Sent Items if it is not showing already.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on account name > Subscribe > Then check the "Sent" folder and others you would like to sync...

Comment: That's it. If you don't enable syncronizing, "Sent Items" (and many other folders) won't even show up in the Account Settings!